# IndexError: list index out of range right after printing len(list) > 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I literally have these two lines of code in sequence:

```
print(len(counter.ondas))
onda = counter.ondas[-1]
```

I got `13` printed for the first line and it crashed giving me tracebook to the `onda = counter.ondas[-1]` line saying `IndexError: list index out of range right after printing len(list)`.

It works thousands of times before crashing. I have no clue on how to approach this problem.

Output for `print(counter.ondas)`:

```
[Onda([<workers.mov.Mov object at 0x244EA050>], [Candle(4, 'GBP_JPY', Timestamp('2017-06-12 16:59:00'), 138.884, 138.897, 138.674, 138.76, 10957.0, True)]), Onda([<workers.mov.Mov object at 0x245073D0>], [Candle(4, 'GBP_JPY', Timestamp('2017-06-12 16:59:00'), 138.884, 138.897, 138.674, 138.76, 10957.0, True)...]
```

Output for `print(type(counter.ondas))`:

```
<class 'list'>
```

Output for `print(isinstance(counter.ondas, list))`:

```
True
```

Full Error Traceback

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\joaoa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
        result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
      File "C:\Users\joaoa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
        return list(map(*args))
      File "C:\Users\joaoa\PycharmProjects\aquitania\general_manager.py", line 88, in load_observer_manager
        observer_manager.update_load_run_data()
      File "C:\Users\joaoa\PycharmProjects\aquitania\observer\management\observer_manager.py", line 78, in update_load_run_data
        self.load_run_data()
      File "C:\Users\joaoa\PycharmProjects\aquitania\observer\management\observer_manager.py", line 91, in load_run_data
        self.feeder.exec_df(df[self.start_date:])
      File "C:\Users\joaoa\PycharmProjects\aquitania\data_source\feeder.py", line 429, in exec_df
        self.feed(candle)
      File "C:\Users\joaoa\PycharmProjects\aquitania\data_source\feeder.py", line 98, in feed
        self.make_candle(ts, candle, criteria_table)
      File "C:\Users\joaoa\PycharmProjects\aquitania\data_source\feeder.py", line 126, in make_candle
        self.set_values(ts, candle)
      File "C:\Users\joaoa\PycharmProjects\aquitania\data_source\feeder.py", line 310, in set_values
        ts_obs.feed_complete(self._candles[ts])
      File "C:\Users\joaoa\PycharmProjects\aquitania\observer\management\observer_loader.py", line 100, in feed_complete
        observer.update_last_candle(candle, store_candle)
      File "C:\Users\joaoa\PycharmProjects\aquitania\observer\abstract\observer_abc.py", line 93, in update_last_candle
        self.set_observe(self.update_method(candle))
      File "C:\Users\joaoa\PycharmProjects\aquitania\observer\ondas\ondas_inside.py", line 393, in update_method
        self.update_routine(counter_id=2, candle=candle)
      File "C:\Users\joaoa\PycharmProjects\aquitania\observer\ondas\ondas_inside.py", line 412, in update_routine
        onda = list(counter.ondas)[-1]
    IndexError: list index out of range
    """

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/joaoa/PycharmProjects/aquitania/general_manager.py", line 145, in <module>
        gm.run()
      File "C:/Users/joaoa/PycharmProjects/aquitania/general_manager.py", line 113, in run
        list_of_observer_managers = self.load_all_observer_managers()
      File "C:/Users/joaoa/PycharmProjects/aquitania/general_manager.py", line 60, in load_all_observer_managers
        observer = currency_pool.map(self.load_observer_manager, list_of_currencies)
      File "C:\Users\joaoa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 266, in map
        return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
      File "C:\Users\joaoa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
        raise self._value
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: can you show the output of `print(counter.ondas)` and `print(type(counter.ondas))`?

Comment: what is `counter`? Please post how that is defined

Comment: @Joe counter is a list of custom objects, I'll add that to the post. CORRECTION: counter is a custom object, counter.ondas is a list of custom objects

Comment: @joaoavf I don't think `counter.ondas` is a list.

Comment: @paul, I added a print(counter.ondas) to the original post. Will do the later.

Comment: @joaoavf you can try `onda = list(counter.ondas)[-1]`.

Comment: @Alex, I am running the code just to make sure.

Comment: @Alex, just ran it and it is a list.

Comment: @joaoavf try running `print(isinstance(counter.ondas, list))` just to be sure

Comment: @Alex, finished running it, it prints `True`

Comment: can you provide the full error traceback

Comment: @joaoavf pretty sure one of the `counter.ondas`s in the `multiprocessing.pool` instances is empty.

Comment: Is this a thread pool? Is that list shared among threads? This looks like a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to idenfity the issue. The error was being thrown in a separate process than the one that was being printed and for some reason the error ocurred only after the process that was printing the results was interrupted by another unrelated error.

Weird behavior, but now I am able to tackle the problem.

Debugging in a single process mode helped a lot.

Thank you for your help.